# Why isn't my <ul> inheriting from my <div>?

Tags: css, list, html

I've been working on this for awhile so I might just be really tired but why isn't my ul inheriting properties from my div (specifically the list-style-type). Here's my html:

```
<div id="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Opinions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
#navbar {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Certain characteristics are inherited automatically in CSS, there are many which need explicit to inherit or need to specify to increase the weight of the inherited property. make #navbar ul {..}

Comment: It's a theoretical question about CSS heritage. Seems not all styles can be herited from parent element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`list-style-type` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type) is an [inherited property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance), so your `ul` *is* getting the style applied to it. However, there's something else at play of which you are probably not aware that is overriding it.

All browsers apply default (or "user agent") styling to elements so that there is *some* sort of base styling to any page, even without defined CSS (this is why CSS Resets are popular -- they get rid of default styles). What is happening here is the browser's default styles are overriding your inherited styles, because the default styles specifically target the `ul`, which gives the default styles a higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than the inherited styles.

If you inspect the list ([here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4G2hq/)) with browser developer tools (I used Chrome 31), you'll see what I explained above. I also provided a screenshot below of this.

[image]

The solution? Directly target your `ul`. Even if the selector is just `ul`, it will be applied *after* the default user agent styles, and so will override them (because now they have the same specificity, the last-applied rule wins).

```
#navbar ul { /* or in this case, just `ul` would work */
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: While the answer points to the right direction, here is how the browser works out the "rules": "If" there is no cascaded value for a property, only then does the inherit logic start taking place. In this specific instance, the list gets a cascaded value from the user-agent (browser) styles. Thus,  the browser stops there and does not (need to) find out what the inherited value is (which means the inherited value from the div never gets applied - the browser has already stopped because it found a cascaded value from the user agent styles).

Answer (score 5):

Try this,

```
#navbar ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to target the ul or li specifically for that property.

```
#navbar ul{
    list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Although you can set any CSS property on every HTML element, not all properties have an effect on every element.

list-style-type definition from w3c says: “Applies to: elements with `display: list-item`. Div tag has't `display: list-item` by default, so there is no meaning to use it on it. Also, not every CSS property is inherited to the child elements.
Use it for the unordered list instead directly.